# PHP MySQL- Change Where statement according to GET variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

Hi i have a table and i want to apply 4-5 sql select queries on this table

**Table**

```
id     name      product       price

1      Amit      car           100000
2      Sumit     car           300000
3      Naina     car           250000
4      Ashu      car           125000
5      Sanjay    scooter        40000
6      Rahul     scooter        32000
```

I want to apply 4-5 queries on this table like First i want to fetch all results where product = car

**Query1:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE product='car'

URL:  www.example.com/product/car
```

**Output:**

```
id     name      product       price

1      Amit      car           100000
2      Sumit     car           300000
3      Naina     car           250000
4      Ashu      car           125000
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE product='car' ORDER BY price

URL:  www.example.com/product/car?sort=plth
```

**Output:**

```
id     name      product       price

1      Amit      car           100000
4      Ashu      car           125000
3      Naina     car           250000
2      Sumit     car           300000
```

**Query3:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE product='car' ORDER BY price DESC

URL:  www.example.com/product/car?sort=phtl
```

**Output:**

```
id     name      product       price

2      Sumit     car           300000
3      Naina     car           250000
4      Ashu      car           125000
1      Amit      car           100000
```

Is it possible to declare an if else statement in advance and use a variable in sql statement and write select statement once.

Like

```
$where="WHERE product='car'";

if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
  if(($_GET['sort'])=='plth'){
    $where="WHERE product='car' ORDER BY price"
  }
  elseif($_GET['sort'])=='phtl'){
    $where="WHERE product='car' ORDER BY price DESC"
  }
  ------
  ------
  ------
}
```

**Query be like:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table $where;
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you try it? Looks alright.

Comment: @Qirel Yeah i am trying since hours...its not working don't know why....

Comment: Debug it then. You know, we don't have access to your computer and cannot run your program to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: "*not working*" doesn't really describe the problem, makes it hard for us to help you ;-) doesn't work *how*?

Comment: how did you execute the select command?

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola I want to assign an statement to "$where" variable and use it in a query like "SELECT * FROM Table $where". $where will complete the select statement...

Comment: Thanks for your time guys....I have found my problem and it has been resolved and working fine...

Comment: I think you cannot do it directly, may be you should use a variable and append the where clause to it. with $name you can set just values for fields.

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola Its working as it is... "Qirel" was absolutely right...No error is in it...

Comment: How did you solved it?

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola Actually by mistake i was writing $where="product='car'" instead of $where="WHERE product='car'"...

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a prepared statement and bind variables. As to ascending or descending order this is not so easy, because ASC and DESC are keywords, and bind variables can be used for column values only, not for keywords. But then, sorting prices descending is the same as sorting by `price * -1`  :-)

```
$product = "car";
$order = "DESC";

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "username", "password");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * " .
                      "from table " .
                      "where product = :product " .
                      "order by price * case when :order = 'DESC' then -1 else 1 end ");
$stmt->bindParam(':product', $product, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->bindParam(':order', $order, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or, if you don't find CASE WHEN as readable, use

```
$order = -1;
...
              "order by price * :order ");
...
$stmt->bindParam(':order', $order, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```